# How to update the text data in a page view using button tap?

Tags: flutter

I've implemented a page view which parses data from JSON. 
I'd like to how to implement a shuffle button with a tap function to dynamically change the data in the pages.

I tried to create a function with an increment option and in the onPressed of the button, I passed it. In debug Console, It shows the number is updated, but in the page view, the data doesn't change.

```dart
var index;

  void _random() {
    setState(() {
      index = Random(index).nextInt(3000);
    });
  }
```

```dart
child: new FutureBuilder(
                  future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                      .loadString('json/quotes.json'),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    var quote = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                    return new PageView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                        return new PageView(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                              child: new Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 19),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "" + quote[index]['Quote'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 30,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontFamily: "fontaa",
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        letterSpacing: 2.25,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),

                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

```dart
child: new RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                  elevation: 10,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: new Icon(
                    Icons.panorama_fish_eye,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _random();
                    print("$index");
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.yellow.shade400,
                ),
```

I need a result in which When I tap the button, In pageView a new text should be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your method and pageview builder in the same stateful widget class? Change the name of your "index" variable as it might be confused with your pageview builder index paramater and declare a default value.

```
var _index;

@override
initState(){
   //initialize the index to random value
  _random();
}

void _random() {
setState(() {
   //not advisable to start the range with index 
   //as the range might get smaller if index is near to 3000
  _index = Random(_index).nextInt(3000);
});
```

}

```
child: new FutureBuilder(
              future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                  .loadString('json/quotes.json'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                var quote = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                return new PageView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                    return new PageView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          child: new Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 19),
                                child: Text(
                                  "" + quote[_index]['Quote'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontFamily: "fontaa",
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    letterSpacing: 2.25,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),

                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                );
              },
            ),
```